# How Can i Load ListView Dynamically Depends on the Value from Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a Spinner,Edit Text, Button and a List View in a View. I want to Load my ListView  from database Depends on the value from spinner. and i'm doing add operation on List View also.

My Doubt is that i wanted to know how can i load my list view depends on the data from spinner?

```
public class myClass extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
DatabaseFAM db;
Spinner No;
String Selected;
EditText user;
Button btnAdd;
String strselected;
ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myews);
    db = new DatabaseFAM(getApplicationContext());
    initVar();
}


private void initAudit2Var() {
    No = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.station);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.er);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    adapterLV = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
    setListAdapter(adapterLV);
    final DatabaseFAM db = new DatabaseFAM(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> station = db.getAllstation();
    ArrayAdapter<String> stationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            station);
    stationAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    No.setAdapter(stationAdapter);
    No.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    Selected = arg0.getItemAtPosition(
                            arg2).toString();   
                    list.clear();
                    list=db.getTag(Selected);
                    adapterLV.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set Adapter of ListView at the Item selection of the Spinner....

```
        mSpinnerLangAttrValue.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ** Add ListAdapter Here **
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add onItemSelected event to your spinner.
2. Depending upon the value of the seletion modify your listView with the required data
3. use Datasetchanged event on the listview

Answer (score 0):

```
          sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
          sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                // Load your list here
                }}
```